# Compute lambda of Poisson distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, logarithms

$p = \lambda e^{ -\lambda }$

If $p$ and $e$ are known. How can I calculate $\lambda$?

I tried on log on both side but it did not help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You say that $e$ is known -- does that mean you're using $e$ as a variable name rather than to denote Euler's number? That would be rather confusing.

In either case, what you need is the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Using the defining relation

$$z=W(z)\mathrm e^{W(z)}$$

(where $\mathrm e$ as usual denotes Euler's number) and

$$-p=-\lambda\mathrm e^{-\lambda}\;,$$

you get

$$\lambda =-W(-p)\;.$$

Note that this is a) multivalued and b) only defined for $p\le1/e$.

If you really did intend to use $e$ as a variable name, we can replace it by $a$ to keep things clear and then write

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
p 
&=&
\lambda a^{-\lambda}
\;,
\\
p
&=&
\lambda \mathrm e^{-\lambda\log a}
\;,
\\
-p\log a
&=&
-\lambda\log a \mathrm e^{-\lambda\log a}
\;,
\\
\lambda
&=&
-\frac{W(-p\log a)}{\log a}
\;.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: I think the LHS of your third line is $-p \log a$ and that $\lambda = -W(-p\log a)/\log a$.

Comment: @Patrick: Thanks -- already corrected; you were faster :-)